# Why does my PowerApp display differently when I click "Edit" vs. "Play"?

Tags: powerapps

I am building a PowerApp - after going to make.powerapps.com, I select my app - if I select "Edit", everything is correct and works as expected. If I select "Play", the layout changes from Landscape to Portrait & there are missing fields and controls on my forms. Does anyone know what would cause it to display differently?

I tried updating the Display settings to lock/unlock the aspect ratio - that didn't resolve the issue. I also tried changing the Scale to Fit & Lock Orientation settings. So far, none of the Display settings have made a difference. The app should display in Landscape, but I click "Play" it keeps changing to Portrait, as well as dropping fields and controls from my form.

Comment: I think it's likely that you haven't published your changes, so when you click play you're seeing your older, published version, instead of your newer unpublished changes.

Comment: That did it! I published the changes and it now displays correctly. Thank you!!